# ffmpeg crop and watermark in a single step

Tags: ffmpeg

We are processing short videos. Most of them are 640x480, recorded by mobile. Many of them have a black frame on left and right.
I would like to watermark the videos and currently using this command.

```
ffmpeg -i IN.mp4 -i WATERMARK.png -filter_complex "overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10" OUT.mp4
```

The problem is that if there is a frame, part of the watermark goes on the frame and only a part is on the actual content. Would like to place the watermark on the bottom right of the actual content.

Are any of these possible, or any other ideas?

a, Dynamically detect the black frames and adjust the watermark position accordingly.

b, Crop the black frame and watermark the content correctly in the same step.

Thanks a lot for your help!

**EDIT:**

I have found that it won't be possible in one step.

1, I can get the crop size

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT.mp4 -t 2 -vf cropdetect -f null - 2>&1 | awk '/crop/ { print $NF }' | tail -1
```

2, Then crop the video

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT.mp4 -filter:v "crop=352:480:144:0" -c:a copy OUTPUT.mp4
```

3, Then watermark it

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT VIDEO.mp4 -i INPUT IMAGE.png -filter_complex "overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10" OUTPUT VIDEO.mp4
```

Is there a way to merge 2, and 3, into a single step?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to merge 2, and 3, into a single step?

You can join individual *filterchains* with a semi-colon:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i image.png -filter_complex "[0]crop=352:480:144:0[bg];[bg][1]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:a copy output.mp4
```

See the [FFmpeg filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html) for additional information.